# AnimationDrawable crashing app

Tags: android, animationdrawable

So I've created my animation list and Ive set up my button but when I click the button which calls the animation method the app closes down and says "Unfortunately, Test has stopped working".

I believe the problem is in the animation method but have no idea what it is and have tried several different ways to fix it.

```
private void homeAnimate() {
    ImageView homeScreenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    homeScreenImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_animation);
    AnimationDrawable homeAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) homeScreenImage.getDrawable();
    if(homeAnimation.isRunning()){
        homeAnimation.stop();
    }
    homeAnimation.start();
}
```

Can anyone see the problem in this method?

Also I apologise if it's really simple I haven't done much Android programming. Though I have done an animation before that worked fine.

Thanks

```
06-22 16:19:53.166: W/dalvikvm(1217): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a20ba8)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1217
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.homeAnimate(MainActivity.java:43)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:41)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-22 16:19:53.216: E/AndroidRuntime(1217):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


06-22 16:07:35.826: E/AndroidRuntime(830): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: post the LogCat of the Exception

Comment: also it looks like you're casting a BitmapDrawable to an AnimationDrawable

Comment: I've never actually looked at the LogCat before but it says OutOfMemory, so I suppose the animation contains image files that are too large? I'll post a bit none the less.

Comment: I'm using jpg's but I'm thinking PNG may be better.

Comment: There should be more to the Exception block than that, usually its about 10 or so lines long. Towards the bottom is a section that will say "Caused by:" which is what we want -- that'll show where the exception occured in your code

Comment: I couldn't see anything that said "Caused by:" but that's everything in red.

Comment: Found the "Caused by:"